# Как программно создать поле в таблице Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Как программно, во время выполнения скрипта создать поле в таблице Mysql ActiveRecord Yii2?
Предположим, что в модели есть соответствующий атрибут, но в таблице его нет.

Comment: Пока ничего не ясно. Можно чуть поподробнее? Типа add column или insert? Обязательно использовать AR? Почему? И в чём сейчас сложности?

Comment: да, чтото типа add column, желательно организовать это внутри AR.

Comment: предыстория: есть рабочая система на mongoDB там вся логика работает как надо (поля и данные добавляются динамически исходя из условий), только потому что база данных позволяет это делать. Теперь мне надо перенести систему на mysql, то нам поля сами не добавляются. То есть получается такая ситуация:в процессе работы AR генерирует поля, и при необходимости пытается добавить данные в них, но в таблице mysql  возможно этих полей нет., По этому их надо добавить и сохранить данные.

Comment: что-то типа или всё же именно add column?

Comment: Если  именно добавить новую колонку в таблицу, то AR не предоставляет таких возможностей, потому что у него назначение другое. DAO - без проблем. или классом из миграций

Comment: Вам надо не изобретать костыли, а перепроектировать БД.

Comment: так вроде работает)):  $connection = new \mysqli("localhost", "user", "123", 'db');
        $query = "alter table settings add column price int";
        $result = $connection->query($query);

Comment: но это и не AR. Я уже написал, если надо: DAO - без проблем. или классом из миграций . Но проделывать это в целом - просто костылище невероятный

Comment: спасибо, дали наводку, буду думать дальше